# Ruby class inheritance and how to avoid calling super twice

Tags: ruby, inheritance, super

I'm constructing a chess game. I'm trying to generate each chess piece with a Combining Enclosing Square, and while I can manually type it into each class, I'd like to do it through inheritance. I can't avoid calling `super` twice per subclass. I'd appreciate any help.

Code:

```
class Piece
  attr_accessor :color, :piece

  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
    @piece = "#{@piece}\u20DE"
  end
end

class King < Piece
  def initialize(color)
    super
    @piece = "♔" if @color == "white"
    @piece = "♚" if @color == "black"
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `Combining Enclosing Square`?

Comment: It's a Unicode character.

Comment: I'm going a little off-topic here, but this seems a little funny to me: `@piece = "#{@piece}\u20DE"`. It looks like `Piece` is the superclass, and you're initializing `@piece` using `@piece` + some unicode. But `@piece` isn't defined until that line, so wouldn't it always just be the unicode `\u20DE`?

Comment: I think it's a poor choice of naming on my part. @piece is defined in the attr_accessor method in the Piece superclass, I think. I should probably change that to something else to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would move this logic out of the constructor entirely:

```
class Piece
  attr_reader :color

  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end

  def piece
    @piece ||= "#{base_piece}\u20DE"
  end
  alias :to_s :piece

  private
  def base_piece
    self.class.const_get(color.upcase)
  end
end

class King < Piece
  WHITE = "♔"
  BLACK = "♚"
end

puts King.new(:black), King.new(:white)
# => ♚⃞
#    ♔⃞
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd define a setter. It's cleaner anyway.

```
 class Piece
  attr_accessor :color, :piece

  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
    @piece = "#{@piece}\u20DE"
  end
  def piece=(piece)
    @piece = "#{piece}\u20DE"
  end
end

class King < Piece
  def initialize(color)
    super
    self.piece = "♔" if @color == "white"
    self.piece = "♚" if @color == "black"
  end
end

k =  King.new('white')
puts k.piece
w = King.new('black')
puts w.piece
```

Result:

```
$ ruby chess.rb
♔⃞
♚⃞
```

Two more things:

- Having a class Piece with an attribute @piece is confusing.
- Use attr_reader if you don't expect to modify @piece. (I'd say a pawn promotion is a new piece, not a pawn changing into a queen).
- Skip the setter, just define to_s, which adds some semantic value.

Comment: You're defining a `piece=` setter but you never use it. Do you mean to do `self.piece = ...` instead of `@piece = ...`? The latter sets the instance variable directly and doesn't invoke the setter.